# Create a random UUID and use it in two different Java methods

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, methods, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to create a random UUID (converted to a string) and use them in two different Java methods, but I'm confused as to how to save the created UUID and pass them to the methods. I'm just plugging in a hardcode string at the moment.

Create method -

```
public void createLocationStream() {
    UUID stream = UUID.randomUUID(); <---- UUID CREATION

    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonKinesis kinesisClient = AmazonKinesisClient.builder()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(awsRegion)
            .build();
    CreateStreamRequest createStreamRequest = new CreateStreamRequest();
    createStreamRequest.setStreamName(String.valueOf(stream));
    createStreamRequest.setShardCount(1);
    kinesisClient.createStream(createStreamRequest);
}
```

Methods to passed to -

Use in Method 1 -

```
    public void addDataToStream() {
        PutRecordsRequest putRecordsRequest  = new PutRecordsRequest();
        putRecordsRequest.setStreamName("location-stream");   <--- HARDCODED STRING
        List <PutRecordsRequestEntry> putRecordsRequestEntryList  = new ArrayList<>();
            PutRecordsRequestEntry putRecordsRequestEntry  = new PutRecordsRequestEntry();
            putRecordsRequestEntry.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap((formData).toString().getBytes()));
            putRecordsRequestEntry.setPartitionKey("partitionKey-%d");
            putRecordsRequestEntryList.add(putRecordsRequestEntry);
    }
```

Use in Method 2 -

```
    public void createShards() {
        GetShardIteratorRequest readShardsRequest = new GetShardIteratorRequest();
        readShardsRequest.setStreamName("location-stream");   <--- HARDCODED STRING
        readShardsRequest.setShardIteratorType(ShardIteratorType.LATEST);
        readShardsRequest.setShardId("000000000000");
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure what you issue is. You create a GUID value. Is your issue that you want to retain this value between HTTP Requests? For example, you app performs a POST request and you generate this value and then you want to retain it for other HTTP requests?

Comment: @smac2020 I need method 1 and 2 to use the randomly created GUID value from the create method, but it needs to be the same value that it is randomly created. It sounds silly, but I'm not sure how to pass that unique value.

Comment: If its during the same HTTP request, its quite easy. Store the value in a data member then you can use it within all method calls. If you want to access this value between HTTP Requests (you need to access this GUID value when ever the app is used), its a bit more involved. However, there are ways to do it. One way is to store the value on the cloud using something like Secret Manager.

Comment: @smac2020 Would it make sense to save the GUID to the DB during creation and then call it from there in the later two methods?

Something akin to : 

        UUID stream = UUID.randomUUID();
        request.setUuid(stream);

Comment: That is one way to handle this use case to make sure the GUID value is available for your app to use when ever the app is started. You can look at using a NO SQL database such as DynamoDB.

Comment: @smac2020 I would ideally love to use that, but I have to use MySQL

Comment: That will work too. Is your MySQL running as a RDS instance?

Comment: @smac2020 Yes it is.

Comment: Do you know how to write an app that can query data from a MySQL RDS instance?

Comment: @smac2020 Not from an RDS instance, no. I need the latency to be as close to real time as possible, so I'm thinking it might be best to save to the RDS instance but post data to my frontend directly from the stream, if possible. Wouldn't querying streaming data from RDS and then posting it to the frontend increase the latency dramatically?

Comment: Why don't  you just pass uuid as an argument to both methods?

Answer (score 1):

You stated that you are not sure how to interact with a MySQL RDS instance from an app. Here is an AWS Tutorial that will help you get up and running and perform the required tasks such as setting up the MySQL SQL instance and working with Inbound Rules. This example is a Spring BOOT app that tracks work items for a typical Status Report use case.

See:

[Creating the Amazon Relational Database Service item tracker](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker)

There is a lot of logic in this AWS tutorial including setting up the Java Connection.

As far as time questions, you will need to write your own tests, etc to determine how long it takes to query a GUID value from an RDS database table.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so very much for all your assistance @smac2020